# Optimize chains of single-qubit u1, u2, u3 gates by combining them into a single gate in Qikist

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, qiskit, programming

Can anyone explain how Qiskit does the merging of single-qubit gates for the purpose of optimization?

1. `u1(lambda1) * u1(lambda2) = u1(lambda1 + lambda2)`
2. `u1(lambda1) * u2(phi2, lambda2) = u2(phi2 + lambda1, lambda2)`
3. `u2(phi1, lambda1) * u1(lambda2) = u2(phi1, lambda1 + lambda2)`
4. `u1(lambda1) * u3(theta2, phi2, lambda2) = u3(theta2, phi2 + lambda1, lambda2)`
5. `u3(theta1, phi1, lambda1) * u1(lambda2) = u3(theta1, phi1, lambda1 + lambda2)`
6. Using Ry(pi/2).Rz(2*lambda).Ry(pi/2) = Rz(pi/2).Ry(pi     2*lambda).Rz(pi/2),
7. `u2(phi1, lambda1) * u2(phi2,lambda2) = u3(pi - lambda1 - phi2, phi1 + pi/2, lambda2 + pi/2)`
8. For composing u3's or u2's with u3's,u2(phi,lambda) = u3(pi/2, phi, lambda)

How do they come up with these equations? Is there a property to derive them?

Comment: Have you tried simply substituting the definitions of the different rotations into the formulae and verifying that they work?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by *DaftWullie*, you can verify these formulas direcly by substituing parameters and multiplying matrices describing the gates. Also you can use very useful formula valid for any rotation around an axis $a$ for angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$
R_a(\alpha)R_a(\beta) = R_a(\alpha+\beta). 
$$

This can be used in the first identity for example, since $U1$ is in fact *z*-rotation (up to global phase).